# How to validate "fields" in form formidable on the node.js?

Tags: node.js, validation, formidable

How to validate "fields" in form formidable on the node.js ? I want to make sure that all of fields are filled by the user. in express we have something like `req.validationErrors()`

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an error and then catch it with `form.on('error', fn)`.
Here is a simple example:

```
// Create a Route (/upload) to handle the form submission.
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var requiredFields = ['name', 'email'];

    // Whenever a field / value pair has been received.
    form.on('field', function(name, value) {
        if (requiredFields.indexOf(name) > -1 && !value) {
            // field is required and its value is empty
            form._error('Required field is empty!');
            return;
        }
    });

    // Send error message back to client.
    form.on('error', function (message) {
        res.end(message);
    });
});
```